What kind of "balun" or "choke" or device is this? (Picture)
The image suggests that this is called a "1:1 current balun" but I'm not sure that (a) it actually is a true balun   and (b) that it's a current balun at all. Also notable is that it doesn't specify the ferrite type to be used other than its shape, which may make identifying this design harder.
Visually it's a trifiliar wrapped toroid, two of the the three wires directly from antenna coax (SO-230) to screw terminal wired straight through, but with an unusual (to me) cross-wired third wire element. The three-wires-together wiring pattern (trifiliar) here seems to result in a dead short between the blue and red conductors at DC.  Perhaps it is intended to not allow DC current to pass through, but it is not an isolation transformer as a circuit, as shown?

Is this second image's related question's image a true balun schematic:

I am trying to figure out what VARIATIONS of balun and chokes of various kinds exist and which one the image first in this question IS.
What I thought I remember reading (probably in books about audio transformer applications) is that a circuit should isolate the left and right side more like this third image. [Update: Which would be fine at 500 hz but not very good at 5 mhz]

Here's an image of an balun constructed with three wraps but which does not follow the first schematic, which may be a further variant.


Your first image shows a Ruthtroff  1:1 voltage balun. The windings should be trifilar (even twisted) and not like in Ruthroff's paper with the third (green) wire separate but on the same core. If you are looking for a current balun with a "third wire", put the third winding on a different core. The reason for the third winding is to extend the bandwidth of the current balun down to lower frequencies. Usually a double apperture core is used for this.

The caption on your first figure, “1:1 Current Balun,” is a real head-scratcher. That transformer traces its roots back to Ruthroff’s landmark 1959 paper, where it appeared in his Figure 2 as a 1:1 voltage balun. He wound it differently, with the third winding done separately, not trifilar.

Here’s the ironic bit about this transformer: the third winding (5-6)? Completely unnecessary for it to work well. Honestly, I’d leave it out entirely. Ruthroff claimed it was crucial for providing a path for the magnetizing current, but that’s not really true. It just works in a bit different way.
Without that winding, what you have is a 1:1 Guanella balun—described in another groundbreaking paper many years earlier—or, as most folks know it, a 1:1 current balun. That's same thing as your second figure. It works very well as a balun as well as a common-mode choke. Sometimes less is more, even in transformer design.
Both Guanella’s and Ruthroff’s papers are cornerstones in the world of transmission line transformers.

If you’re diving into the world of baluns and transformers, their papers are must-reads—a real education in the art of turning bright ideas into practice.
https://www.qsl.net/kp4md/ruthroff.pdf
https://hamwaves.com/chokes/doc/guanella.1944.pdf
Now, about your third schematic: it’s not a balun at all. It’s just a plain old transformer. I wouldn’t trust it in an RF power line unless you’re working exclusively in the HF low bands. Expect it to be lossy. Smart engineers wouldn't do that way.

Thank you!   So far, experimenting with the first schematic built a balun that doesn't seem to work very well at all.   It mostly seems to to turn RF into heat, and my analyzer sees an unholy mess, and my transceiver sees high SWR everywhere.    Moving back to something closer to your first image, two wires, and similar to several ARRL HANDBOOK examples, seems to work well, but I do not understand if it is in fact a transformer, and if in fact, a balun SHOULD BE a transformer, or SHOULD NOT be one, per se.  The green wire seems not so much unnecessary as a BAD idea to me at the moment.

These are transformers and baluns and all. The names like "balun" and "choke" are just functional aliases for certain types of transformers. Conventional transformers like your third figure is particularly bad in RF, especially above about 10 MHz range. When I see people trying to use one of those, that's like a litmus test for their level of RF experience. Skilled people much prefer transmission line transformers like your second figure, and everything described by Guanella and Ruthroff. Study and use those, not conventional transformers.

I've said this before, and say this again. Forget about elementary textbook depictions of transformers, conventional transformers. Those that looks like your third figure. They work well at 50/60Hz, audio frequency, 455kHz, switching mode power supply circuits, MW AM radio, but not much higher. Real RF engineers avoid them like the plague unless there's a reason to go for it (and that's very rare). Sounds like ARRL Handbook might be the source of bad information.

Re the little green wire, did you double-check the winding direction when you connected it? It shouldn't make a drastic difference, like you said. @WarrenVA7WPX

I don't think the ARRL Handbook directly told me to do an audio style transformer circuit. I think I intuited balanced and unbalanced AUDIO CIRCUITs that I was familiar with, and misunderstood the nature of the transformer application.

RE Little Green wire, I'm pretty sure it's a direct short at DC between the two sides, and is doing something unwanted,  but perhaps I'm wrong about this weirdo balun.  Still not sure what it is.  It isn't described in the ARRL handbook, but it doesn't describe a LOT of baluns that exist in the world.

In RF baluns, DC short is irrelevant (unless there is a DC bias or power on top of the RF line). The question is whether the direction of the winding and the connection points are correct. The unbalanced source would see a broadband RF short if you connected the green wire in the reverse direction.

That is interesting. because both my antenna analyzer and my NanoVNA show crazy unusable high SWR and crazy impedance swings with the green wire in place, and I'm sure it's not reversed.   I had the analyzer and vna attached to the transceiver coax in, and a 50 ohm resistor to simulate the load. It's also possible that I have other shorts as the wire is magnet wire with a clear dielectric coating. that coating could be damaged.

If constructed correctly, I know that the transformer works fine, so something must be wrong with the construction. It could be compromised insulation, as you said. Did you use different colored magnet wires to make sure you are not mixing up the windings? With one color, once you build the transformer, it's very tricky to troubleshoot. DC conductivity test is useless unless you remove all joints first.

@WarrenVA7WPX It's hard to tell from your photo, but your green appears to be wired in reverse. Either that, or the label in the photo is wrong. You should always distinguish which wire is from the dotted side and which ones are non-dotted. (1 - 1', etc.) Also, it's good to label the wire with a paint marker so you can discern 2 and 3. The best is to use teflon jacketed cords in multiple colors... PVC has 10x higher dielectric loss than FEP or PTFE and also melts at a lower temperature. PTFE/FEP jacketed cords are found on eBay and AliExpress.
